# Routes not working in react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I am trying to setup react router in my react application. The versions I am using are

```
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
```

I am using reacr-router-redux for this appilication.

**Application Flow:** I have two pages in my application: Login Page and App Page. Landing page should be Login Page and when I click on Login button then it should take me to the App Page. There are three sections in App Page: Header, Sidebar and Content Section. Content section is dynamic and renders two different layouts depending on which link is clicked in sidebar. Only one component at a time can be rendered in content section.

**Problem:** I have defined routes. I get landed to LoginPage correctly. When I click to Login, I get navigated to app page also correctly. But when I click a link on sidebar, all the components (sidebar, header and content section) disappears.

**My code**

main index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import Root from './Container/Root'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {ConnectedRouter} from 'react-router-redux'
import store, {history} from './store'


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <div>
                <Root />
            </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Root/index.js

```
import  React, {Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import LoginPage from '../../Pages/LoginPage'
import App from '../../Container/App/App'
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const styles = {
    container: {
        height: '100vh',
        width : '100vw',
        position: 'relative'
    }
}

class Root extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <main>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={LoginPage} />
                        <Route exact path="/app" component={App} />
                    </main>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Root
```

App.js  (here's where the problem is)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Sidebar from '../../Components/Sidebar'
import TriviaPanel from '../../Components/TriviaPanel'
import Header from '../../Components/Header'
import ImagePanel from '../../Components/ImagePanel'
import LoginPage from '../../Pages/LoginPage'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          {/*<LoginPage/>   */}
        <Header/>
          <Sidebar/>
          <div>
              <main>
                  <Route component={TriviaPanel} />
                  <Route exact path="/trivia" component={TriviaPanel} />
                  <Route exact path="/image" component={ImagePanel} />
              </main>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

MenuPanel/index.js (This is the sidebar I change the content component from)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const styles = require('./sidebar.css');

class MenuPanel extends Component {

   constructor(){
       super();

       this.state = {
           activePanel: "trivia"
       }
   }

    toImagePage(){
       this.setState({activePanel:"image"},()=>{
           this.props.toImagePage()
       })

    }

    toTriviaPage(){
        this.setState({activePanel:"trivia"},()=>{
            this.props.toTriviaPage()
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="navbar-side">
                    <div className="tessact-logo"></div>
                    <div className={`navbar-item ${this.state.activePanel == "trivia"? "active":""}`} onClick={() => this.toTriviaPage()}>
                        <a className="navbar-item-link"><span className="fa fa-comment"></span> TRIVIA</a>
                    </div>
                    <div className={`navbar-item ${this.state.activePanel == "image"? "active":""}`} onClick={() => this.toImagePage()}>
                        <a className="navbar-item-link"><span className="fa fa-picture-o"></span> IMAGES</a>
                        <div className="navbar-item-inside">
                            <a className="navbar-item-inside-link">PERSONSS</a>
                            <a className="navbar-item-inside-link">BRANDS</a>
                            <a className="navbar-item-inside-link">OBJECTS</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="navbar-item">
                        <a className="navbar-item-link"><span className="fa fa-tags"></span> KEYWORDS</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    toTriviaPage: () => push('/trivia'),
    toImagePage: () => push('/image')

}, dispatch)


export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(MenuPanel)
```

I tried this also

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    {/*<LoginPage/>   */}
                    <Header/>
                    <Sidebar/>
                    <switch>
                        <Route exact path="/trivia" component={TriviaPanel}/>
                        <Route exact path="/image" component={ImagePanel}/>
                    </switch>
                    <Route component={TriviaPanel}/>

                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

What is wrong in what I am doing? In previous versions of router it was pretty simple to define child routes and everything. I am new to this router v4.

Comment: in App.js your first route does not have a path. Change the order of it to be last Route

Comment: That is because I want it to be default

Comment: Then change its order. I mean Route without path should be the last one.

Comment: In our app we use it like this: Inside `<Provider>` we have `<BrowserRouter>`, inside it we have `<Switch>` and inside that we have `<Route path=."...." component=.... />`

Comment: Tried this also. Not working. Check the update. I have added it. Tell me if something is wrong in that.

Comment: For right now just remove the default route. And now check if its working. Also check the answer given by someone else.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your routes. i faced the same problem recently. so here is your problem. you clicked the link for 'app'. the url becomes

```
http://localhost/app
```

now all routes defined inisde the app component must be /app/link.

therefore

```
  <link to='/trivia'>Trivia</link> //example. use whatever metohd you are using to route instead. use the given url
  <Route exact path="/trivia" component={TriviaPanel}/>
```

becomes

```
  <link to='/app/trivia'>Trivia</link>
  <Route exact path="/app/trivia" component={TriviaPanel}/>
```

this tells react that it needs to go into the app component and then search for the route tag in its jsx to render.

Comment: what is the solution? Can you please add that also?

Comment: your url instead of /trivia it should be /app/trivia

Comment: Just one doubt. Why push doesn't work.? I was using push instead of link

Comment: I think you need to wrap all your components in withRouter HOC for it to work

Comment: It is working but when I refresh the component it doesn't comes shows up. For example if I refresh localhost:3000/app/trivia then screen is blank. I want to see the page when I refresh also.

Comment: That you have to configure your server to ignore routes which are handled by react router. On refresh your server is handling the request not react, so you need to tell it to ignore those routes. Or you can try hashrouter instead of browser router . C